# Can I add my App in iPhone Share Screen?

Tags: iphone, xcode, share

I recently, developed an application that works as an Add on in android.
When a user likes anything either it is a photo or a document and clicks Android Share Button "My App" displays within that share area along with Facebook,Twitter etc..

Is it possible with iPhone? through X-code? so that i could share that document or photo on my
app.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of research i ended up this issue:

1) iPhone does not provide this facility But android do have share intent to achieve this functionality.

WAKE UP IPHONE GUYS ANDROID IS GIVING THIS FROM THE LAST 2 YEARS.....

Comment: Not necessarily both the platform should have the same concepts and functionalities.